# How to connect sybase database from iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sybase

1)Is it possible to connect sybase database which is in windows machine from iOS Application  for iphone development?

2)If yes,How can we connect and access data base data through query from iOS and see the result in Iphone simulator?

Comment: sybase to an IDE called XCode.... Not possible. Did you mean Cocoa?

Comment: Try a google search; I hit this page first time: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01213.0200/doc/html/vhu1266613693128.html

Comment: See this blog and website: http://www.slashdb.com/2013/03/14/database-gateway-for-mobile-and-web-apps/

Answer (score 0):

[SAP's Sybase Unwired Platform](http://www54.sap.com/solutions/tech/mobile/software/solutions/platform/overview.html) allows you to build mobile applications that can take advantage of your enterprise data sources.